# AWS: nginx as LB apache as backend

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, aws

I'm developing a new web platform for my business on AWS, the current configuration uses nginx+ as load balancer and some apache instances as backend.

With the service of autoscaling I'm able to exploit the features of dynamic configuration of nginx+, so every time a new web server is activated the configuration of nginx is automatically update and the new backend is hooked to the balancer.

The problem is this: if by chance nginx crashes or is restarted the balancer lost its dynamic configuration and the balancer does not route more the connections to a running web server. 
I thought to sort it out with a cron on backend that did a check on the state of the balancer, but this is not a solution very clean and functional.

I'm looking for the solution as automatic as possible, which can guarantee the balancing mechanism with the least possible work for the operator. Any idea?

Comment: What not use an AWS Elastic Load Balancer?

Comment: @jordanm we must maintain nginx as load balancer, we need to set request headers before passing the requests to the web server. For the operation of our application ELB is not very useful.